# No command 'toco' found

Tags: python, ubuntu, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I'm trying convert my newly trained mobilenet model to tflite for using it with an Android App by following the Google codelabs. 
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets-2-tflite/index.html#3

I'm on a Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Machine.It say's

> No command 'toco' found

Google told me that toco does not work on Windows, but I'm on a Ubuntu machine and my TensorFlow works perfecly for training and inference.

Since TensorFlow works and toco comes along with TensorFlow, toco should ideally work and it doesn't.

> It is installed as a command line script, with TensorFlow, so you can
>   easily access it.

Need help fixing the issue with toco(TensorFlow Lite Optimizing Converter)  so that I can convert my model to a .lite file and run it on Android device.

Comment: Your not asking a question.   Please consider what help you want and ask for it.  We are not mind readers.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out @LhasaDad. Should've read the draft before posting. Update the question.

Comment: Did you make sure your directory that the toco command is in is on the path?

Comment: @LhasaDad This kind of helped. There's a problem with the version of TensorFlow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the version of TensorFlow. TensorFlow Lite was recently introduced and I didn't check for the version of TensorFlow(Was using 1.4). I updated my TensorFlow version to 1.7 which contains the lite related modules under the contrib folder, after looking at the GitHub repositiry.